# Replace similar DLL's with different names?

Tags: powershell

i hope you could help me with my little problem.
There are 2 different folders, A and B.

In Folder A, there are a lot of DLL's data. In Folder B, there are also a lot of DLL's.

for example:

Folder A:

ThreeServer.Host.**v13.1**.Core.dll

Hello.This.**v13.1**.Is.More.dll

Folder B:

ThreeServer.Host.**v12.0**.Core.dll

Hello.This.**v12.0**.Is.More.dll

All DLL's Names in Folder A just differ with "v13.1" to the DLL's in folder B (v12.0).

Now i want to replace all DLL's in folder A with the DLL's in Folder B.

All is based on language **PowerShellISE/Powershell**.

Does anybody know a solution for this or methode ?

Comment: What do you try so far ? Is it your homework ?

Comment: it's a little function of my project:


$DLL = gci $FolderA | where {$_.extension -eq ".dll"} 
#$DLL | Foreach-Object {if(Test-Path $FolderB\$_) {robocopy "$FolderA" "$FolderB "$_"}} 


but this methode is just going if the name is similar, but **it isn't**

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a combination of `Get-ChildItem` to get the file list, regular expressions to grab the non-version part of the file names, then wildcards to see if there is a match in the destination directory.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $DLLPath -Filter *.dll |
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -Match '^(.*)(v\d+\.\d+)(.*)$' } |
    Where-Object { 
        # uses $matches array to check if corresponding file in destination
        $destFileName = '{0}*{1}.dll' -f $matches[1],$matches[3]
        $destinationPath = Join-Path $FolderB $destFileName

        # Add the destination file name mask to the pipeline object so we can use it later
        $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name DestinationPath -Value $destinationPath

        # Check that a corresponding destination exists
        Test-Path -Path $_.DestinationPath -ItemType Leaf
    } | 
    Copy-Item -WhatIf -Verbose -Destination { 
        # Use Get-Item to get the actual file matching the wildcard above.
        # But only get the first one in case there are multiple matches.
        Get-Item $_.DestinationPath | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty FullName
    }
```

See [about_Regular_Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847880.aspx) for more information about regexes.

Comment: Maybe i have an initial solution. I could go in folder A, then i get all DLL's with gci $DLLPath | where {$_.extension -eq ".dll"} |Where-Object { $_ -Match 'v13.1' } ...Then i save the filenames in a variable and replcae v13.1 with v12.0. After this i testpath the dlls in Folder B. If they correspond, replace the name v12.0 in Folder B with v13.1. Then i could use robocopy for coppy dlls in folder a to folder b, right ?

Comment: @helpme That's a good start.  I updated my answer.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer, it nearly works, the filenames in FolderA corresspond always to the other ones with the different version number in the name. But always it shows me the whatif when i start my skript, it dont copy and replcae the FolderA'files with the new version number, in folder b :( but the what-if method is very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$folderA = "C:\Work\Tasks\test\A"
$folderB = "C:\Work\Tasks\test\B"
$oldVersion="v12.0"
$newVersion="v13.1"
$oldFiles=Get-ChildItem $folderB  | ForEach-Object { $($_.Name) }
Get-ChildItem $folderA  | ForEach-Object `
{ 
  foreach($oldFile in $oldFiles )
  {
   if($($_.Name) -eq ($oldFile -replace $oldVersion,$newVersion))
   {
     Write-host "File Replced: $($_.Name)"
     Write-host "File Deleted: $oldFile"
     Move-Item $($_.FullName) $folderB 
     Remove-item "$folderB\$oldFile"
   }   
  }  
}
```